# Confused about output from copying a list

Tags: python, list, copy

Hopefully not too basic of a Python question, but I stumbled upon this while writing a function and am a bit confused.

I am trying to run through a for loop and create multiple lists where the first item is the same. If I use this method, all seems fine.

```
current_list = [1]

for each in range(5):
    each = current_list + [each]

    print(each)

[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
```

But if I try to make a copy of the list and append to it, I get `None`

```
current_list = [1]
for each in range(5):
    each = current_list.copy().append(each)

    print(each)



None
None
None
None
None
```

Do I need to deep copy the list? What is the best way to copy the contents of the list?

Comment: `list.append(value)` doesn't return the list, it returns `None` - the appending happens in place. On the other hand the `+` operator creates a new list and returns it.

Comment: Is there a better way then to append and then return the entire list?

Comment: Ideally you'll just do something like `lst.append(value)` and then just use `lst` later on when you need it since it's in place. If you really want to return you can create a function: `def append(lst, val): lst.append(val); return lst`, but I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: Neither shallow nor deep copying is at all helpful here.